# Upload large file async without disposing it

Tags: c#, .net-core, filestream

I'm building a .NET Core 3.1 WEB API that will receive a large file(up to 500MB), if it's valid, return a 200 response to the client and only after that, upload the uploaded file to an Azure Blob Container.

The issue I've got is that the Request/Stream is being disposed(I believe) after I return the response to the client, and it doesn't give me any errors nor is it uploaded.

I've tried a few alternatives but with no success:

- Task.Run()
- Locking the stream,
- Copying the stream to a new variable
- Synchronising the stream,
- Hosted Service with a Background Queue

The only way the file is successfully uploaded is if either I persist the file locally or force the user to wait, but I would rather not do that if I can.

Has anyone got an idea how I can accomplish this?

---

EDIT:

I create a resource on the database with the file upload operation( and return a 202 with the file upload operation id) and I update it's status depending on the success of the upload to the Azure Blob Storage.

The user can check the upload status on a different API endpoint.

I would just like to know if there's a way of persisting the file stream or any object really after the response is returned.

Comment: If the user does not wait, then how will you communicate with the user if uploading to the cloid was successful?

Comment: It seems you're doing 2 things: 1) Download the item from the user. If success/fail, let the user know. 2) Upload to the cloud. For 1 you can make the user wait. 2 is your own worry. Therefore 1 can be the web API. 2 has to be some other process that runs on its own and takes files and sends them to the cloud. Those failures need to be handled by you since you're the client.

Comment: As an aside, returning [202 Accepted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_HttpStatusCode_Accepted) may be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Also you don't need to keep trying alternatives. Even if Task.Run worked, it would have been a bad solution. You just need to really understand how the web works on a request/response model then try things. Anyhow, you need something like I suggest earlier with a separate process for doing the uploads to the cloud.

Comment: I've edited the original post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser provided an `Expect: Continue` header. Then you can fail a request based on the provided request headers, before the client has sent any file data. Or then respond with a 100 continue and read the file data.

However, if you want to keep that file data, you will have to copy it somewhere before you can return a status code to the client. Into memory, onto a local disk, or stream it all the way to your back end blob container. That's just how HTTP works.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is having a fundamental issue....

> if it's valid, return a 200 response to the client and only after that, upload the 
>   uploaded file to an Azure Blob Container.

There are a whole universe of cases where this ca nresult in the client getting 200 and you not uploading it to the blog container, so the 200 is a lie. As such, you should NOT do it that way PERIOD. So, the question is moot.

On top, you can not really do that because asp.net will dispose the file that you got because that is how asp.net is working - the variable is part of the request context and thus disposed at the end of it.

Comment: I add a resource to the database(not the file) based on the call and upload the database with the status of the file upload to the Azure blob container. The 200 is therefore valid since I've created a resource in the database based on the request sent.

As such, is there a way to .net core(not asp.net) from disposing the file whilst it's being used?

Comment: First, it is not valid because you do not upload the file, but you report all done to the client - what if the backend fails in between? This CAN happen, bad news. Second, as I said - no. The file resource is owned by WebApi and once you return it is not valid anymore.

Comment: You're correct - 200 is not valid.

I should, as devNull suggested, be returning a 202 not 200.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way the file is successfully uploaded is if either I persist the file locally or force the user to wait

You could copy the stream to a MemoryStream, and pass that to a background process to upload.  But it will take a lot of memory, and wouldn't survive an application restart.

Copying the stream to a local file, and passing that to a background process would at least, not take up 500MB of memory per request, and could be made to survive an application restart.

Comment: Thank you David Browne,

I think I'm going to have to do this.